# Playing audio on browsers

Tags: html, audio, cross-browser, html5-audio

I'm trying to play audio on this [website](http://www.claudialennear.com). I'm using audio tag so that the music plays when someone visits the home page. However, I don't see the audio working. I've added wav, mp3 (128kbps) and ogg formats.  The audio doesn't play on Chrome. It plays on Edge, IE. I'm trying to make it work so that it plays on Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Its pretty straight forward so I'm confused on where it is going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```html
<audio autoplay>
   <source src="audio/abc.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
   <source src="audio/abc.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
   <source src="audio/abc.wav" type="audio/wav" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
```

Comment: It seems to be working properly. check your browser settings.

Comment: I'm on Chrome. I've tested it on https://www.browserling.com/ . It doesn't work for Safari, Chrome or Firefox. What settings should I be looking at? I've cleared cache.

Comment: Go to site settings and then audio. make it "Allow"

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. All the browsers permissions are good.